# PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR

Tags: json, phantomjs

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Parse error
 at D:/Dev/test-data.js:9

Line no.9 is commented, I got error when composing the following JSON

```
var contactId='53d6e7ce-a874-4f35-a7ad-49373d0a56ae'
var localDBData = {
           ContractContacts: {
                            [contactId]: {
                                ContactContactId:contactId
                                ContactName: 'sam',
                                IsInactive: false
                               }
                        }
                        }
```

If I remove the JSON data it's working fine. am sure that I got an error because of creating the nested object i.e., [contactId]

Comment: You have got an error on `D:/Dev/test-data.js` on line 9. Without more code, this is all we can say.

Comment: Line no.9 is commented, I got error while composing the following JSON


var testID='53d6e7ce-a874-4f35-a7ad-49373d0a56ae'
 var localDBData = {
                ContractContacts: {
                    [TestID]: {
                        ContactName: 'xxxx',
                        IsInactive: false
                    }
                }
         }

If I remove the JSON data it's working fine. am sure that I got an error because of creating the nested object. i.e.,[TestID]


*Error Line no shows totally wrong, actually it was commented code

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted has a syntax error. There is a comma missing after `contactId`. The corrected version looks like this (stars to emphasis change):

```
[...]
[contactId]: {
    ContactContactId: contactId*,*
    ContactName: 'sam',
    IsInactive: false
}
[...]
```